# Best way to test JPA?

Tags: jpa, junit

I am working on JPA project and I want to have unit tests (although as a database is required, in this case it will be more as integration tests.)

What is the best way to test JPA project? jUnit can do that ? Is there other better way ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Your question is too generic. Ask a specific problem. What do you mean  by testing a JPA project. Mocking EntityManager or something?

Comment: and apart from those problems with your "question" you haven't defined "best". Not the place for such questions ...

Comment: Thank you for your anwers. Testing JPA project I mean testing DAO, testing that adding entities to the database is fine, the scheme is right etc.. and for "best" I mean the easiest solution because I have never used jUnit before! Thank you again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have given limited information on the tools/frameworks you are using and a very general question, but I will give a quick answer on the points you raise. These are just pointers however as I believe you need to do a good bit more leg-work in order for you to figure out what is best for your particular project.

**Junit** allows you to target your class methods with specific parameters and to examine the return values. The returned values maybe an entity that should have certain field at certain values, a list of entities with certain expected field values, exceptions etc., etc. (Whatever you methods are). You can run your test as you introduce new functionality, and re-run them to test for regression as development proceeds. You can easily test edge cases and non-nominal stuff. Getting Junit up and running in Java SE/EE is quite straight forward so that could be a good option for you to get stick-in with testing. It is one of the quicker ways I use to test new functionality.

**Spring/MVC** – Using an MVC framework can certainly be useful. I have used **JSF/Primefaces**. But that is principally because the application was to be a JSF application and such development tests gave confidence that the ‘Model’ layer provided what was needed to the rest of the framework.  So this provides some confidence in the model/JPA/DB layers (it is certainly nice to see the data that is delivered) but does not provide for flexible, nimble and targeted testing you might expect from Junit.

I think Dbunit might be something to look at when you’ve made some progress with JUnit.
See http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/

> DbUnit is a JUnit extension (also usable with Ant) targeted at
>   database-driven projects that, among other things, puts your database
>   into a known state between test runs. This is an excellent way to
>   avoid the myriad of problems that can occur when one test case
>   corrupts the database and causes subsequent tests to fail or
>   exacerbate the damage.